# I am unable to get the value from the object. Getting undefined object error

Tags: arrays, json, object, react-native

I am new to React Native and I want to get the object value and print it in the Text but I am getting undefined is not an object (evaluating json['label'])

Below is the format:

[ {"id":"1","label":"abc","icon":{"uri":"imagepath"}}]

So for now I have store it and trying to save the label value in variable.

```
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
 const json=this.state.typeofCountry[i];
  const originallable33 = json['label']; 
  marqueeItems.push(
    <View>
       <Text >
       {originallable33}
      </Text>
     </View>
  );
}
```

It would be very helpful if anyone explains me how to parse the array and object and get any specific value from it.

Comment: if any of these replies answered your question please accept one of them, its bad manners to ask for help and not accept an answer

Comment: @PeterPocket, After struggling I came across the real issue ..it was my api response used to get late and the render was set earlier..so the data was not displaying...As I am new to it I need to struggle a lot for finding out the actual issue..Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to take an array of data and use it create a new array of components that use this data. Using a `for` loop can be quite bulky and difficult to read so I think you should rather use the `map` function.

This is how I would solve it:

```
// this.state.typeofCountry is an array so we 
// can use the map function to iterate over it.
// The callback function passes each entry of the array as a parameter, 
// you can name this parameter anything you want!

this.state.typeofCountry.map((country) =>  (
    <View>
       <Text >
       {country.label}
      </Text>
     </View>
))
```

To read more about map and other really useful array functions, I recommend you head over to MDN to see what else you can use. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

this is due to `this.state.typeofCountry[i]` returning undefined
(most likely due to `i` being bigger than the array itself)

safely extract items without undefined errors by adding a simple null check -

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  const json=this.state.typeofCountry[i]; // json could be undefined

  if(json?.label){
    // notice the ?. operator (this is called optional chaining)
    // if true, "label" is present

    const originallable33 = json['label']; 
    marqueeItems.push(
      <View>
       <Text>
         {originallable33}
      </Text>
     </View>
    );
  }
```